# How do I visualize death rates (represented by ODEs) of a population

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, mathematical-modeling, visualization, simulation, python

So, I found [this](https://www.google.com.ph/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjIloCo9tjTAhXONpQKHWZAA3MQFggkMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Ffiles.umwblogs.org%2Fblogs.dir%2F8053%2Ffiles%2F2013%2F04%2FKellyBrownHonors.pdf&usg=AFQjCNF-LwxeFFwmdJ6NR_oOyAy6n9Gw-g&sig2=jxK9Fp0o5Fk-K7BsdmOk9g) paper on the decline of honey bee populations (see page 8 for the model). I want to use the differential equations to visualize, say 1000 bees (as dots) as they die over time. Is this possible with Python or can I use a niche software?

Comment: Matlab is quite fine to solve ODE's...

Answer (score 1):

From what I see from the paper, the $\mu$ term is the death rate and proportional to the population. This indicates some sort of "competition" because the higher the population, the more intensive the effect of "competition" and thus more bees die. To visualize **just** the death effect on the graph, I suppose by solving 
\begin{equation}
\dot{H}=-\mu H \\
H\left(0\right)=1000
\end{equation}
and plot over a good deal of grid points to see the exponential decline. However, in conjunction with other effects (the first two terms) in the model, even if you solve the ODE numerically and plot it, I do not know where to pick out specifically where the deaths are happening. It would be intrinsic in the graph.